# NodeJS - How to inject all dependencies in existing project?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, html, socket.io

I have an existing web project with few dependencies like

- Materialize.css
- lodash.js
- script.js
- style.css

  and so on...

I think socketIO can't load files like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I want to make my application communicate with socket.io, but when I launch the server file (index.js), I can see my page but totally broken with no css and no scripts.

My index.js looks like that :

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', 'utf-8', function(error, content) {
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        res.end(content);
    });
});


var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);


io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Un client est connecté !');
    socket.emit('message', 'Vous êtes bien connecté !');
});


server.listen(8080);
```

So have you an idea how I can tell the server to inject all the ressources of my existing website ?

Comment: You could include a huge switch case or if statement that detects what asset was requested and serve it, just like you're doing with index.html, but that's not going to be very... dry or fun or reusable. Express would make this a bit easier, but the better option would be to front your app with nginx or apache so tha tyou can serve static assets through apache/nginx, as well as your node server using a **reverse proxy**, all under the same port.

Comment: Do you understand that you've created a web server that, no matter what resource is requested from the web server, you send `./index.html`. Your web server has to serve all the web resources needed for your site.  When `materialize.css` is requested, your web server needs to serve that, along with all the other files your web site requests like the `socket.io.js` file.  Usually, one does not hard code static asset files like this.  Usually, you set up some generic infrastructure to serve the static assets.  There are many ways to do this (Express.static, nginx, custom code, etc...).

Comment: Yes and I think I misunderstood this part. That's not just index.html that I want to include but all its dependencies too!

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample code you're using was meant just to provide a simple example of what to serve to the client, not to actually serve HTML pages or other static content.

With Express you can do this:

```
var app = require('../app');
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Then in app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));    //to render static content files to the browser from a predefined static resource directory
```

Notice how `express.static` points to where static content should be located. In this case, it's in the `/public` folder (it can be any other of your choice). That's where `index.html`, `*.css`, and all the resources you mentioned should be placed.

A detailed example can be found [here](http://blog.modulus.io/nodejs-and-express-static-content).

In the end, the code you pasted in your question will work without having to open and serve the `index.html` file inside `http.createServer`; it's not meant for static content.

Comment: Yes I think too now. Do you think it's easier to do with the socketIO example? Something like this : `app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});`

Comment: Personally, I don't think so. I know that the websockets protocol is all the rage these days, but there are specific use cases where it serves best. Stateless HTTP is still suitable for most web requests, including serving static pages. There's a cost with socket.io, as a connection must always be open (or open most of the time) in the server. Can such server handle all your clients? Is it then worth the cost? If you answer yes, sure, go for it. However, notice that socket.io _starts_ with HTTP (long polling) then it may switch to websockets if available (continues below)...

Comment: So, if one already has HTTP, why not to serve the page right there and then? I hope this information helps you!

Comment: Roy, one more thing. How will you deploy your solution? Will you have multiple Node JS instances running behind `nginx`, for example? If so, you can serve your static pages right from `nginx` (or any other web server). This way you don't take CPU/io time away from Node JS. Also, `nginx` can act like a load balancer and a firewall to your Node instances. However, if you deploy Node directly, with nothing in front of it, using Express to serve static pages will work. Good luck!